# FQL Query to See If User Likes A Post

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

In my app I need to check whether or not a user likes a post(s). To do this I'm using the FQL query

```
SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE object_id=postid AND user_id = me()
```

For most posts, this works fine and it returns the post_id of the liked post. However, I found that if the post that was liked was posted on a page as opposed to posted by a friend, this doesn't work (doesn't return the post_id). So if I liked post a, posted by a page, and post b, posted by a friend, the query would only say that post b was liked.

Oddly enough, when I run a query to see ALL the posts the user likes

```
SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE user_id = me()
```

both posts a and b appear as liked. However I would like to avoid sorting through a list of 100s of posts that the user liked to find whether or not the user likes the post(s) in question, and the response times to get the full list could be a lot longer. Is there any way to get the query to show all liked posts (regardless of who posted it)? Or is this a restriction or bug with the api

Answer (score 1):

To check whether user liked a post we need to get data form stream table instead of like table, please follow the below request

```
Request : 
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/fql"];
NSMutableDictionary * params1 = [NSMutableDictionary 
dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:
@"SELECT likes FROM stream WHERE post_id = '%@'",
postID],@"q",facebookOfflineAccessToken,@"accessToken",nil];
```

In Response we will get Total count of likes and user_likes fileds

```
Response :
"user_likes" = 0 //for not liked,     
"user_likes" = 1 //for like
```